# Writing JPEG image in java as uncompressed still destroys data

Tags: java, image, jpeg

I was making an application that hides data in LSBs of a JPEG image. Knowing that JPEG is a lossy compression and has a default compression of 70%, I changed it's parameters to 100% thus assuming that it wont destroy any data in the image. Here is the code.

```
File output = new File(gui.getOutput()+".jpg");

ImageWriter jpgWriter = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("jpg").next();
ImageWriteParam jpgWriteParam = jpgWriter.getDefaultWriteParam();
jpgWriteParam.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);
jpgWriteParam.setCompressionQuality(1f);

FileImageOutputStream outputStream = new FileImageOutputStream(output); 
jpgWriter.setOutput(outputStream);
IIOImage outputImage = new IIOImage(image, null, null);
jpgWriter.write(null, outputImage, jpgWriteParam);
jpgWriter.dispose();
```

The image that was created was indeed loss less, but the data I stored within the pixels were destroyed. (I checked it by reading the inserted data in the LSB and it wasn't the data I stored in the image).

What should I do to avoid the data being destroyed?

Comment: Maximum quality for a JPEG is still compressed and encoded. Your approach cannot work.

Comment: when you `setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);` if you look at the docs, it throws away all of the previously set parameters. It gets rid of all of the compression parameters that are already a part of the jpg `defaultWriteParam`. That is, if I understand the javadocs correctly. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageWriteParam.html#setCompressionMode%28int%29

Comment: 100% compression quality only applies to quantization step. There are several steps involved in the JPEG compression process, especially the errors introduced during the DCT step cannot be 100% recovered later.

Comment: @AndrewMedico I am trying to do a steganography on jpeg. I tried reading and understanding jpeg stego but I wasnt able to understand it fully. Like DCT, converting to YCbCr, quantization and the likes.. I would like to know what is the simplest method to apply steganography in JPEG. It will be okay if not 100% of the data is restored by steganalysis, as long as it is near the 100%

Comment: @EthanBrouwer I also thought it that way, that's why i wrote the compression quality after the setting of compression mode. :)

Comment: @dragon66 Is there some code I could study or a tutorial on doing JPEG steganography? I have only done lossless steganography like on png completely. It's way more complex when making a jpeg steganography. :(

Comment: My knowledge to steganography is very limited. Looks like people manipulate DCT to achieve this goal - [link](https://www.blackhat.com/docs/asia-14/materials/Ortiz/Asia-14-Ortiz-Advanced-JPEG-Steganography-And-Detection.pdf). Looks quite complex though.

Comment: You may have to deal with JPEG encoder with source code as someone did with my GIF encoder a long time ago when he wrote his thesis about steganography..

Comment: @dragon66 there's been a problem on an encoder which I have seen. Do I use this encoder by calling it in my application? modify it? or do an application similar to that? How do I decode?

Comment: I guess you need to have access to the DCT source part, change it and use it to encode the image but I am not sure how it work.

Answer (score 0):

A must read [api](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageWriteParam.html#compressionQuality), and it only applies to quantization step